# NextJs Tailwind Google Font not working when weights are selected

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, tailwind-3

I am trying to add a google font to NextJS via CDN. For some reason it works, but only when I add the font without selecting any font weights. Does anyone know how I can include the full font family?

Works:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter&display=swap"rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Does not work:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Full _document.tsx

```
import Document, {
  DocumentContext,
  DocumentInitialProps,
  Html,
  Head,
  Main,
  NextScript,
} from "next/document";

class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(
    ctx: DocumentContext
  ): Promise<DocumentInitialProps> {
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);

    return initialProps;
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head>
          <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
          <link
            rel="preconnect"
            href="https://fonts.gstatic.com"
            crossOrigin="true"
          />
          {/* <link
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter&display=swap"
            rel="stylesheet"
          /> */}
          <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"/>
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}

export default MyDocument;
```

tailwind.config.js

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
const defaultTheme = require("tailwindcss/defaultTheme");
const headerHeight = "80px";

module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./layouts/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "node_modules/daisyui/dist/**/*.js",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ["Inter", ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
      },
      height: {
        header: headerHeight,
      },

      padding: {
        header: headerHeight,
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [require("daisyui"), require("@tailwindcss/typography")],
};
```

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap");
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

html,
body,
#__next {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Method 1

For the google font to work,

1. Go to Google Fonts and select the font you want in your app, like here I am using [Dancing Script](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Dancing+Script) with all weights.
2. Now copy the import URL given in `Use on the web` section.

   ```
   @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dancing+Script:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap');
   ```
3. Paste the import in `globals.css` file like this.

```
   @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dancing+Script:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap');

   @tailwind base;
   @tailwind components;
   @tailwind utilities;
```

4. IN `tailwind.config.js` file , Inside themes => extend add a new property of `fontFamily` and give the font a name like `Dancing` here.

```
 theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
       Dancing: ['Dancing Script', 'cursive'],
      },
    },
  },
```

> **Note:** The rules in the array should be the same as given in Google fonts.

5. Now you can give any tag the className of `font-fontName` in this case `font-Dancing`.

```
    <h1 className="font-Dancing">This is using a custom font</h1>
```

#### Method 2

Try to use the `font-bold` class in the code as an alternative.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I updated my post to include globals.css, where you see my import. For some reason, it still does not work. I've tried using font-sans, and also changing the font name in tailwind to Inter and using font-Inter, but neither worked.